# Why are we repeating the same information twice when viewing an user activity tab?

Tags: bug, profile-page, top-bar

When opening the site switcher (little SE icon in the top right) when viewing any user activity on their profile page, the user information from the top bar is repeated.

Is this a desired behavior? It seems to be too specific.

[image]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on Meta.SE: [Extra user card and two "log out" links in the Stack Exchange menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368759/348196)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I _think_ the repetition used to be on the Profile tab as well but was fixed [when the Profile tab was made responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964/348196).

Comment: I'm more curious about why the extra card is *only* shown on the activity page and the Developer Story page, and not the actual profile page, nor the settings page. Also, it's not shown on your Meta SE profile page. Very inconsistent all around.

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite as redundant as it looks:

[image: Mobile view, without top bar reputation]

On mobile (or a small desktop window), there is no top bar rep. This drop down is the only easy way to see your own rep.

Do we remove the drop down reputation until the window gets too small for rep to be in the top bar? And where would your username go (since that's the only place it's shown)? It doesn't seem worthwhile. The drop down could just be made taller to show more content.

Comment: It _is_ redundant (at least partially). Having the username, rep, and badges might be worthwhile but there are two "log out" links (why?) and also on desktop, all that information is already there on the top bar. So, why show an extra user card, especially on the profile page where that information is visible even on mobile?